# How to run java applications JDK13 on JRE?

Tags: java, java-8, java-13

I have made an a java app with JDK 13. I created a exe file with launch4j. But nobody can run it because everyone has the jre 1.8 version and it wont start... I has to include the java jdk 13 with installation and set the java_home with that ?

Comment: set your  java compiler version to 8, so it will run for other

Comment: As of Java 11, there is no "official" JRE. You are supposed to use [`jlink`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm#JSWOR-GUID-CECAC52B-CFEE-46CB-8166-F17A8E9280E9) to create a distributable version of your application. You don't need launch4j anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR - If you want to distribute a Java 13 application, the **best** option is to use `jlink` to create the executable.  This avoids the user having to install *any* JDK or JRE to run your code.

---

Clearly, users cannot run your application with a Java 8 JRE or JDK.  A typical Java 13 application will make use of features that are not present in the Java 8 platform.  But even if it worked, free Java 8 will be end-of-life in April 2021, and at that point:

- It will stop getting security updates, making it (in theory if not practice) unsafe for your customers to use.
- It will be more difficult for your customers to find free Java 8 binaries.  (Paying Oracle for a license will be an option though.)

But Java 13 is problematic too.  That will be end-of life in September 2020!   And besides, JRE distributions are no longer available.

Finally, application installers with embedded JREs were always somewhat problematic:

- It was easy for software suppliers to forget to update the installer when there was a security patch to the JRE.
- It was difficult for system administrators to add the embedded JRE to the list of things that were automatically updated.  Especially if they allowed end-users to install the application for themselves.

---

The best approach will be to do the following:

- Use `jlink` to create the distributable for your application for all platforms that you support
- Update to Java 14 as soon as practical
- Whenever a Java patch release with security fixes is released, assess what has been fixed and (if warranted) create new releases of the distributable for your customers to install.

If you don't want use `jlink`, another alternative would be to develop your code to run on Java LTS releases.  (The current LTS release is Java 11, and the next one will be Java 17 which is planned for September 2021.)

- Using an LTS release would allow you to release your code as JAR files.
- Embedded JREs are a bad idea; see above.

Comment: [adoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/support.html) has Java 8 support until "At Least May 2026". April 2021 is just Oracle.

Comment: Not just Oracle.  This is what Ubuntu are saying about their OpenJDK packages.   But either way.  While it is OK for an org to decide to keep using Java 8 in-house after the official end-of-life, a software supplier continuing to develop and ship a Java 8 - based application to customers (without an option to upgrade) would be pretty shoddy ....

Comment: Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048548/support-lifetime-of-openjdk-8-in-ubuntu-xenial-16-lts

Comment: I interpret that Ubuntu link as saying when LTS ends for those releases of Ubuntu (and Java is immaterial to that decision). Perhaps I'm reading too much into it.

Comment: EOL for Ubuntu 18.04 is April, 2023: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases.  So, yes you are.   (I am equating EOL with "end of standard suppport".  Canonical say the EOL is 2028, but that refers to "extend security maintenance" which is a paid for option.)

Comment: I still don't think I'm going to recommend the default Ubuntu JDK over adoptOpenJDK or Liberica. But it certainly sounds as though they've decided to push a major Java upgrade in the LTS stream - of course, they could still change their minds in the next thirty-six months. It took a really long time for python2 to "die".